# Lógica com data no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, lógica

Pessoas, estou desenvolvendo uma planilha para controlar melhor a produção da fabrica em qual trabalho, não entendo muito de excel e estou com uma dúvida que pode ser que seja simples resolver. Seguinte, tenho 35 máquinas disponiveis para a produção, e sei o tempo demorado para essa máquina finalizar uma ordem de produção com uma quantidade X, eu tenho uma lista de pedidos, e nela calculo o tempo de produção na máquina, e ja gostaria de encaixar a data do próximo pedido baseado no prazo de termino do anterior: vou demostrar: 
pedido 1 = 6 máquinas (tem 35 sobram 26) começa dia 04/06 
pedido 2 = 37 máquinas (tem 26 sobrando, posso começar a produzir simultaneo), começa tambem dia 04/06
 porém como o primeiro pedido vai acabar, no dia 05 posso pegar as 6 máquinas para dar continuidade no pedido 2, e assim por diante, ele ir somando essas datas, então terei um gantt da produção, e ainda no pedido 2 terei 2 ordens de produção pendentes (37-35).
Alguma ideia de como fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

desde já agradeço!

Comment: Ou está mal explicado ou a sua dúvida me parece ser mais matemática do que de Excel. Se você dividir o número de pedidos pelo total de máquinas e arredondar para cima, para o próximo inteiro, você terá o número de "ciclos" necessários para a produção. Por exemplo, com 50 pedidos e 35 máquinas (`50/35 = 1,43 => teto(1,43) = 2`) são necessários 2 ciclos: no primeiro as 35 máquinas produzem 35 pedidos e no segundo elas produzem os 15 pedidos restantes. Dai é só multiplicar esse número de ciclos pelo tempo que as máquinas levam (supondo, claro, que todas levam o mesmo tempo).

Comment: Se for isso mesmo que você quer, não é necessário VBA. Basta calcular o número de ciclos e multiplicar pelo tempo em uma fórmula.

Comment: Obrigado por responder @LuizVieira, eu estava usando essa lógica, porém eu tenho uma lista de pedidos, e nela cálculo o tempo de produção na máquina, e ja gostaria de encaixar a data do próximo pedido baseado no prazo de termino do anterior:

vou demostrar:
pedido 1 = 6 máquinas (tem 35 sobram 26) começa dia 04/06
pedido 2 = 50 máquinas (tem 26 sobrando, posso começar a produzir simultaneo), começa tambem dia 04/06
porém como o primeiro pedido vai acabar, posso pegar as 6 máquinas para dar continuidade no pedido 2, e assim por diante, ele ir somando essas datas, então terei um gantt da produçã

Comment: Oi Denis. Bom, não é o que está escrito na pergunta. Por que você não a edita e melhora o texto, incluindo esse exemplo e até mesmo uma imagem com o gráfico que você imagina? Vai facilitar que obtenha uma resposta.

Comment: Opa @LuizVieira, alterei, agradeço a força!

Comment: Pra o que voce está querendo é mais facil instalar o msproject. Mas como imagini(sya situaçao pode ser igual a minha) a empresa nao disponibiliza da licença do software. Só uma pergunta: nos quadriculados coloridos vc está inserindo algum valor?

Answer (score 1):

O que o usuário @bp002 disse talvez seja a única solução se você quer que o sistema realmente "conte" o tempo - nesse caso, você estaria desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando a linguagem Visual Basic. Mas você pode arredondar a divisão para ter a quantidade de ciclos que seriam necessários para cada ordem de produção usando a função **teto()**. Eu acredito que isso resolveria seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível usando vba, imagine uma lista de tamanho N onde você adiciona as OPS para as máquinas, e uma thread que olha essa lista, pega uma posição da lista, processa, e marca com 0, dai você uma um timer global, e um interno dentro da thread das máquinas, logo você usa um laço de repetição iniciar as threads que irão ler a lista, das 35, a thread precisa, saber que posição != 0 ,se pode processar a posição, posição == 0, já foi processado, dai ela deve procurar outra posição, caso não encontre a thread se encerra.

Comment: bah n tem nem ideia de como começa haha obrigado por responder @bp002